# Why are the svg files created in Inkscape suddenly cannot be opened in Graphic?

Tags: macos, svg, core-graphics, inkscape

Till today, I was able to create SVG files using Inkscape, then open the file (and modify it) using Graphic on my Mac. Today, suddenly, when Graphic opens the svg files (saved as "plain SVG" or "Inkscape SVG"), the files are blank. If I drag the file into Graphic, I get an error message: "the file ... cannot be imported as a valid image".

So I updated Inkscape to 1.1, the current version. Still, the problem persists. Searching yielded little insight except that perhaps the incompatibility may be in the first line of the svg files. Pulled up a working SVG file, indeed it has a different first line. Copying it over made no difference. So what do I need to do to be able to open Inkscape svg files in Graphic (which I am far more familiar with)?

The first couple of lines from one of the invalid files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="595.275591pt" height="841.889764pt" viewBox="0 0 595.275591 841.889764" version="1.2">
<g id="surface71726">
<path style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(99.215686%,99.215686%,99.215686%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 10.785156 426.429688 L 10.785156 169.285156 L 580.644531 169.285156 L 580.644531 683.570312 L 10.785156 683.570312 Z M 10.785156 426.429688 "/>
```

And the first line and half from the working svg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" width="744.23" height="512.157" viewBox="0, 0, 744.23, 512.157">
  <g id="layer1">
    <path d="M608.765,190.665 L608.765,190.665 L602.066,192.274 L602.066,192.349 C599.976,192.587 597.668,192.769 595.613,192.904 L595.334,190.477 C603.239,189.938 610.32,188.216 616.595,185.536 C616.
```

Comment: There's not much to go on here. I bit more of the files would be useful. Try trimming the faulty file down to something minimal that fails.

Comment: Just as a wild hunch. Try saving as "Optimized SVG" and make sure "Convert CSS attributes to XML attributes" is on..

Comment: Appreciate your response. Tried various methods with no success. Will look for other apps. It's a shame as I used Inkscape to convert rasterized images to SVG all the time. I initially posted a few more lines but couldn't post because it exceeded the word limit.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- open a working file
- delete all the contents from it
- save as ... template with your favourite name
- now use the new template for your next drawings

I suspect the difference in the header that you have posted here explains why 'Graphic' cannot deal with the valid SVG document.

You could also try and report a bug for 'Graphic', if they take customer reports.

Comment: By saving as a new template, you mean saving in Graphic? or saving in Inkscape? I'll submit a bug report.

Comment: I mean in Inkscape.